# Use non-local numbers to receive messages

Tags: twilio

Can I use a Canadian number to send and receive SMS from US numbers?
And also a German number, which is marked as international, for receiving and sending SMS in Europe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming related question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find SMS best practices per country, below.

Canada
https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/ca/sms

Germany
https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/de/sms

You can replace the country code in the URL above to see the best practices for other countries. Scroll down on each page to see best practices.